Showing if y=DES(k, x), then /y = DES(/k, /x)
The textbook gives a similar example of proving the below problem:
Based on this, how would I go about showing $y={DES(k, x)} => \overline y=DES(\overline k, \overline x)$, within the same format as the answer for the above example? Thanks

Does this answer your question? Complement property of DES, Proving DES complementation property: y = DES(k,x) ⟹ /y = DES(/k, /x)

No it does not, unfortunately. I wrote that question and the answer was not close to what is expected as in the above example solution

Rather than post a new question asking the same thing, please edit and clarify your previous post. Also, I strongly suspect that this is homework (if you just wanted to understand the DES complementation property, why is it important to match the style/format of a textbook?), and none of us here have any incentive to put more work into your homework than you put into it.

@Mikero Thing is if I do not ask it to be in similar format, people would throw unsensible suggestions that are nowhere near the expectations.
